# Dynamic inspection of table element on Blue Prism

Tags: dynamic, blueprism, rpa

I inspected an element and this is the path
"/HTML/BODY(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(2)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/TABLE(1)/TBODY(1)/TR(2)/TD(2)"

I want to make a loop, and the only dynamic part is TR(2) 
"/HTML/BODY(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(2)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/TABLE(1)/TBODY(1)/**TR(2)**/TD(2)"

I created a data item with a name of [Row] that has an initial value of 2 and created the path on the application modeler as dynamic.

I placed on these on "params"
/HTML/BODY(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(2)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/TABLE(1)/TBODY(1)/TR("&[Row]&")/TD(2)

The error is 
"Internal : Data items must be between [ and ]. Text must be between " and ". Functions should be in the form FunctionName()"

Answer (score 1):

When passing a Dynamic parameter, the parameter itself must be a valid Text string. As such, enclose the entire Path string in quotes:

```
"/HTML/BODY(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(2)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/TABLE(1)/TBODY(1)/TR("&[Row]&")/TD(2)"
```